# Salesforce SDK uninstallation from XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, salesforce

I want to uninstall salesforce sdk completely and have not been able to find any documentation on this. I want all elements of salesforce sdk to be removed.

thanks

Comment: Do you have a question? So far you have simply made some statements.

Comment: Instead of making statements about what you want to do, you should phrase your needs as a question. Right now we don't know what you actually need help with. What have you tried? What exactly do you need help with? Did you have instructions for installing the Salesforce SDK? Look in the same place for instructions to uninstall. Or simply reverse or undo the installation.